# Function with more choices

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a simple key stroke counter code that prints number of entered letters. However I am trying to figure out how to make a function so it recognizes 1 letter from 2 letters (singular and plural). I would like to add also `'stroke'` in my code, and when the keyboard key is entered only once Id like it to print `"You entered 1 stroke"` instead of `"You entered 1 strokes."`.

I tried something but cant really move forward:

```
print('Start typing: ')
count = raw_input()
print('You entered:'), len(count), ('strokes')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use normal conditionals, e.g. using a conditional expression:

```
print "You entered:", len(count), 'stroke' if len(count) == 1 else 'strokes'
```

Also, just for fun, the overly clever for the sake of brevity solution *that you should not actually use*:

```
print "You entered:", len(count), 'strokes'[:6+(len(count) != 1)]
```

or:

```
print "You entered:", len(count), 'stroke' + 's' * (len(count) != 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if` and `else`:

```
if len(count) == 1:
    print 'you entered: 1 stroke'
else:
    print 'you entered: {} strokes'.format(len(strokes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple arguments to print, you can also use string formatting:

```
print "You entered {} stroke{}".format(len(count), "s"*(len(count)!=1))
```

Admittedly, the last part is a bit exotic, but you can of course also do

```
print "You entered {} stroke{}".format(len(count), "s" if len(count) != 1 else "")
```

Comment: Make that `len(count) != 1`, since zero pluralizes.